# List template in dynamic data list in Liferay

Tags: list, templates, liferay, dynamic-data-list

How can I develop a list template for a dynamic list in Liferay?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you'd expect the out come to be?

Comment: I want to display the records using a velocity template

Answer (score 2):

There is some info in the online documentation for - Dynamic Data Lists - [Make it pretty: creating custom displays](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/make-it-pretty-creating-custom-displays).

Also in a series of blogs about Dynamic Data Lists - [Part III](http://www.liferay.com/web/marcellus.tavares/blog/-/blogs/12150383)

Answer (score 0):

I used Asset publisher instead of Dynamic data list to display a web content with multiple templates.
I will post it in liferay website soon.