# How can I develop a list template for a dynamic list in Liferay with action buttons?

Tags: templates, liferay, velocity

[[List template in dynamic data list in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834462/list-template-in-dynamic-data-list-in-liferay)](http://foo.com)

I have already read this post and also another webapplicationdeveloper blogpost but not find any idea to get action button in customly applied template to dynamic data list.

I have also  tried including that default record_action.jsp of dynamicdatalist portlet in vm template but its not working and also set the property below

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables =
```

in **portal-ext property** but still I am not getting the action button in my custom template

I have already tried this :

```
#
set (
$categoriesService = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil").getMethod("getService", null).invoke(null, null))

My answer is: Yessss, it works. But I want use a jstl lib (e.g. <aui> or <ui>) as well. In my opinion the simpliest way to do it is include jsp file to themeServletContext. Put your file.jsp into your theme:

your-theme/docroot/path/to/your/jsp/file.jsp

and paste this piece of code into your vm (for example portal_normal.vm):
$theme.include($themeServletContext, "/path/to/your/jsp/file.jsp")
```

In this case it unable to find the $theme variable my page displaying the **$theme** as it is...:( 
Please help:

Comment: You tried a very wrong way to solve your issue. Have you resolved meanwhile or it's still a open issue?

Comment: No,Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave velocity, it's too poor to use taglib, and switch to freemaker language: more powerfull and full support of taglib.

Here there is an example to use freemaker for theme develment, but it's good starting point also to template in dynamic data list.

https://www.liferay.com/it/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/using-freemarker-in-your-theme-templates

Look also freemaker guide: http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html